# I made my navbar fixed and now it's transparent no matter what I style the background color to be. How can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, navbar, background-color

I tried to create a fixed bar with this code, but after I created it, it became transparent even after I added a background color.

```
.header-nav{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide context to the question and maybe more code where you are using the class?

Comment: Could you include what you've tried to resolve the issue? Such as applying a height to the element to check flow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some context to your code, or clarify your question, and fix your formatting next time you ask a question. This will help more people who have the same question find your post, and also help people read and understand your question. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by transparent but it sounds like you might be seeing content *on top of* the header, not underneath it. Try setting a `z-index` on your header to force it to the top of the stack.

```css
.header-nav{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
  z-index:2;
}
```